# Can I do a mass attribution if I got all the data from one location but different users?

Tags: attribution

I am looking into doing a project and instead of creating my own icons, I would like to use some from [Flaticon](http://www.flaticon.com/). Most are made by different users and each one can be downloaded for free, but it requires that you credit the author.

Can I credit them by saying something like "Icons provided by various Flaticon users" or will I need to credit each person individually?

Comment: I personally like the approach with a footer "Icons under CC-BY-SA 3.0 by various authors(link to attribution page)" and at the attribution page, show all icons you use, with a name and a link to where the work can be found. When the icons are grouped, this can work fairly well for fairly large amounts of different icons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flaticon [requires you to attribute each author](http://support.flaticon.com/hc/en-us/articles/202798381-How-to-attribute-the-icons-to-their-authors):

> In order to use an icon you must attribute it to it's *[sic]* author, so we will be able to continue creating new graphic resources every day.
>
> > Icon made by [author link] from www.flaticon.com
> >     E.g.: Icon made by Freepik from www.flaticon.com

**From a legal perspective:** The icons are under copyright by their respective creators; you cannot legally use them without permission. You can't have permission unless you follow the rules the authors have laid down for reuse of their work.

**From an ethical perspective:** Attribution is not a punishment, or merely a way for you to admit that you didn't create 100% of the visuals in your project. It is a mechanism to *give credit* to the authors who created the work you're using. The authors generously let you use their work for free; they only ask that their names and site links be included.

Flaticon is a repository of work from various artists, and saying *where* you found an artist's work isn't the same as attribution. By saying "Icons provided by various Flaticon users," you are not attributing the authors, but giving a hint about where a user might be able to hunt down authorship information. This is about as useful as (or perhaps even less useful than) simply putting a notice in your project like, "*I found some of these icons on the Internet; if you put them into Google Reverse Image Search you might be able to find out who made them,*" and calling that sufficient attribution.

Fortunately, even if your attribution list is very long, Flaticon allows you place your attributions very unobtrusively. Their suggestions include:

> **For websites:**
>   Insert the attribution on the page of the icon (for example in the page footer) or on the imprint page.
>
> **For printing:**
>   Paste this attribution on the final work so the authorship is known (for instance, in the acknowledgements chapter of a book)
>
> **For app's:**
>   Place the attribution on the credits/description page of the application.

In all cases, you are allowed to place all of your attributions in an appendix, rather than directly alongside the image.

If attributions are for some reason too onerous for you, and you would rather pay money than deal with attributions, you can [pay for a Flaticon subscription plan](http://support.flaticon.com/hc/en-us/articles/202798201-How-can-I-use-Flaticon-s-resources-without-attribution-) which allows you to use most Flaticon resources without attribution. (Resources licensed only under Creative Commons appear not to be covered by the for-pay plan, which appears to grant rights to works under the Flaticon Basic License.)

Answer (score 5):

You need to attribute every person individually.

It appears none of the authors are affiliated with each other, nor to Flaticon, so it makes no sense attributing all their icons to Flaticon. Flaticon doesn't own the copyright, the authors do.

But more to the point, authors choose their license, and it appears some use the [Flaticon free license](http://cdn.flaticon.com/license/license.pdf), whilst others use CC-BY. It's important that you follow each license. At least for these two licenses, for non-website usages, it is ok to section off the detailed attribution in a credits/acknowledgement page, and merely mention that the icons were used under those licenses. So yes, you could say "Icons provided by various Flaticon users", but you must also list the attributions in full somewhere else.